# When is it safe to send a message via Spring Cloud Stream on application startup?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Boot application which has a bean that needs to send a message (using Spring Cloud Stream) once on startup.

Sending direct from a `@PostConstruct` bean method does not work because by that stage it appears that the messaging system is not fully initialised, and an exception results.

I can overcome this using a scheduled task launched from a `@PostConstruct` method with a sufficiently long delay, but the key is what constitutes "sufficiently long"; is there an initialisation event published by Spring Cloud Stream that I can listen for which effectively tells me "it's now safe to send a message"?

Failing that, is there a more robust way to handle this than guessing how long the delay should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never perform "active" operations from a `@PostConstruct` method; it's too early in the application context's lifecycle.

Implement `SmartLifecycle`, put your bean in a high `Phase` (e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) and it will be `start()`ed last.

Put your code in the `start()` method.

Comment: Thank you Gary - I wasn't aware of the SmartLifecycle stuff (I learn something new about Spring every day).

I guess I'm still unsure this is a bullet-proof solution; it delays my component processing to the latest possible phase, but I still don't know whether the Cloud stream system is "ready" at that point.

Comment: Yes, it is robust - the output bindings are started in phase `Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1000`; input bindings are started in phase `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1000` (we don't want to start consuming data before the output bindings are ready). We leave room at each end of the spectrum so user beans can be started earlier than the output bindings or later than the input bindings (or anywhere in between).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Gary.